# Is it possible to enable the Android default keyboard on an HTC EVO 4G?

Tags: keyboard, 2.3-gingerbread, htc-evo, settings

I am not much of a fan of the HTC EVO 4g's custom keyboard, but it appears that they have somehow removed or hidden access to the default Android keyboard input method.

Especially now that the default Android keyboard has been enhanced in 2.3 (Gingerbread), does anyone know of a method to enable the default keyboard instead of HTC's customized keyboard?  I haven't seen an application to do this, but I've noticed that some applications (Vlingo in particular) seem to somehow come up with what appears to be the Android default keyboard.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can - from this thread on [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=875202), you can use the APK on **unrooted** phones, depending on your Android version. Remember to pick the correct version for your phone.

Comment: I tried it earlier today and worked good for me :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried this version yesterday and it did nothing on the EVO 4G.  Bryan, is yours an EVO?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this solution](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=871027)--I'm a little bit nervous about installing it though (it requires flashing the phone.)  Better solutions would be preferred!